# find number of customers added each month

Tags: r

```
customer_id  transaction_id    month  year 
          1    3                7     2014
          1    4                7     2014
          2    5                7     2014
          2    6                8     2014
          1    7                8     2014
          3    8                9     2015
          1    9                9     2015
          4    10               9     2015
          5    11               9     2015
          2    12               9     2015
```

I am well familiar with R basics. Any help will be appreciated.

the expected output should look like following:

```
month   year  number_unique_customers_added
 7      2014     2
 8      2014     0
 9      2015     3
```

In the month 7 and year 2014, only customers_id 1 and 2 are present, so number of customers added is two. In the month 8 and year 2014, no new customer ids are added. So there should be zero customers added in this period. Finally in year 2015 and month 9, customer_ids 3,4 and 5 are the new ones added. So new number of customers added in this period is 3.

Comment: `library(dplyr);
df %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(new_cus = n_distinct(customer_id))
`

Comment: @RonakShah the solution provided here only gives number of unique customers in a month of the given year. However, there could be overlap of the customers between any two months. So this solution doesn't answer my question. right ?

Comment: yes, maybe. Can you update your post with your expected output ? If the answer provided by me doesn't solve your question I will reopen it.

Comment: @RonakShah pls have a look at updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

dt[, .SD[1,], by = customer_id][, uniqueN(customer_id), by = .(year, month)]
```

Explanation: We first remove all subsequent transactions of each customer (we're interested in the first one, when she is a "new customer"), and then count unique customers by each combination of year and month.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` we can first create a column which indicates if a customer is duplicate or not and then we `group_by` `month` and `year` to count the new customers in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(unique_customers = !duplicated(customer_id)) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(unique_customers = sum(unique_customers))

#  month  year unique_customers
#  <int> <int>            <int>
#1     7  2014                2
#2     8  2014                0
#3     9  2015                3
```